# Store geometry Qgis feature creation

Tags: qgis, python

I make a form that has a textEdit wich stores the length of a line. 
How it is possible to store the length of the new created line and put it in the textEdit, when form appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution:

lungimeTextEdit.setText(str(feature.geometry().length()))